# External Hard drive is not detected on disk manager despite showing in device manager

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, hardware-detection, forensics

My external Hard drive is not detected on my computer, It shows up on device manager under but in disk management section it does not appear

I have exhausted all possible reason like,

1. issue with cable
2. Drivers update
3. Port issue[Check multiple ports on multiple devices]

on further investigation from event viewer I see the following attached screenshots for more details

[image: Event viewer error]

[image: Device manager screenshot]

[image: Disk manager not recognizing the disk]

[image: Error Disk in question]

Is there any way I can fix this hard drive and restore it back. I would appreciate any assistance from geeks. Please refer attached screenshots for more details